# django number of consecutive years

Tags: python, django

I am working on a page with stocks and dividends. So to simplify, my model is something like this:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Stock's name", max_length=200)
class Dividend(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('pay date')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
```

I want to calculate number of consecutive years where dividend was paid for each stock. Pure existence of dividend that year is enough. If company paid dividends through 2000-2005 and 2008-2014, I want to get number 7.   What is the best way to calculate it? I came up with:
1. making query for each year if there is any dividend (too many requests)
2. using values() or values_list() to get only list of distinct ordered years and then iterating over that list
I would go with number 2. Is there any better way how to use queryset to calculate this value?
Edit:
3. I noticed [dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#dates) just now.

Comment: Isn't "2008-2014" 7 consecutive years?

Comment: yep, sorry. will fix it :)

Comment: This is doable in SQL, even without analytical functions. It's hard though. I'll see if I can make something up.

Comment: I just need to update this value only once per month or so, so it does not have to be super effective. I was just wondering if there is a better way than values() or dates(). Using raw SQL would be unnecessary difficult.

Comment: How about starting by listing years no dividends were paid? It stands to reason that the difference between no-dividend years yields the number of consecutive years between where dividends were paid. Ex, no-dividend years of 2001, 2004, and 2010 shows that you have 2- and 5-year paid-out periods. That will be a lot fewer things to count and compare.

Comment: Thanks dylrei, that is superb comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought about your comments and this is what I think.
remram: SQL unnecessary difficult.
dylrei: Firstly I thought it's a great idea, but now I am no so sure. There might be one dividend 70 years ago and then 69 consecutive years no dividends. There are a lot if stocks that do not pay dividends and I should be able to get 0 years quickly. Also, I do not know how to get years, were no dividends were paid in Django.
This is what I came up with:

```
def get_years_paying(symbol):
"""
get number of consecutive years paying dividends for Stock by symbol
:param symbol:
:return: number of years
"""
num_years = 0
iteration_year = date.today().year
dividend_years = Dividend.objects.filter(
    stock__symbol=symbol, spinoff=False, special=False, split=False
).dates(
    "date", "year", order='DESC'
)
dividend_years_list = [i.year for i in dividend_years]
while True:
    if iteration_year in dividend_years_list:
        num_years += 1
    elif iteration_year == date.today().year:
        pass  # current year is optional, there will be no dividends on 1. January
    else:
        return num_years if num_years != 0 else None
    iteration_year -= 1
```